# Unable to ssh to raspberry pi with ubuntu from chrome book

Tags: networking, ssh, chromebook, openssh, crouton

I have an Acer Chromebook 14 CB3-431 running ubuntu 16.04 through the crouton method.

I have a raspberry pi that I can ssh from literally any other Ubuntu computer, and even the Crosh shell from the Chrome OS terminal.

I use `ssh pi@hostname.local` which is how I've used ssh to a pi forever while connected to pi wifi

but using the Ubuntu terminal I get the error `ssh: Could not resolve hostname.local: Temporary failure in name resolution`

I am very limited in my ubuntu knowledge but have done some digging and just tried to use `sudo service ssh status` and it returned nothing at all.
Also using `ssh@localhost` just returns a port error.

some random info that may help, I use `startunity` in Crosh to start Ubuntu and it says `(xenial)` in my terminal which is different than standard Ubuntu I believe. I may just reinstall Ubuntu and start over but I'd like to try to resolve the problem as it may just come up again.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect to localhost on another PC doing like this and not to the raspberry.

If I'm using a PC which has let's say IP 192.168.1.10, using localhost will actually point at your local address.

Now what you're trying to do is access a device outside your local address and for doing that you need to use the target device IP.

```
ssh pi@ip-of-raspberry
```

E.g. (assuming your raspberry has ip 192.168.1.30)

```
ssh pi@192.168.1.30
```

Both devices should be on the same LAN or under the same VPN (If you're using it)

Also Ubuntu 16.04 uses systemctl, if you want to know the status of ssh:

```
systemctl status ssh
```

Comment: using the last command gives `Failed to get properties: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1` I am connected to the pi wifi directly also and have never had to use the ip address only the hostname it has(preloaded via SD)